# What is the structure of a good essay?

Tags: essay

Please help me understand various approaches towards developing an essay about issues of society (like women's empowerment, child education, sanitation, Global Warming, etc.).

**Specifically, I want to know how best to structure an essay.**  How do you deploy the various elements (like quotes, introduction, conclusion, and pictures)?

Comment: At what level are you writing?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you think how to structure an essay? It is hard to find a "better" way without knowing "the way" you think it is supposed to be first. Also what is your issue with an essay about these specific issues?

Comment: I want a diplomatic essay

Answer (score 2):

In high school I was taught the following useful essay structure:

1. Introduction: Start *general, abstract* and *universal*, and continually focus more and more tightly until you reach your topic sentence, which should be *specific, concrete* and *particular*, and which describes exactly what you are going to talk about, in order.
2. Body: Expand on what you have promised in your topic sentence.
3. Conclusion: Reiterate what you have just explained in the body.

As far as the body, there are many possible structures.  **Compare and contrast** illuminates one subject by reference to another, showing what is the same, and what is different.  **Persuasive** argues for a specific conclusion.  **Explanatory** explains the details of how something works. **Personal** connects the topic to your own life.  **Critical** looks for the strengths and the flaws in something. These are just a few of the more common structures.  Whichever one you pick, stick to it throughout the essay. Quotes should be used to support what you have said, and should not be expected to carry the weight of the argument themselves.  Visuals can be used to supplement the essay, but the text should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: I want an essay of post graduate level but not of high school